# Can I downsize lua tables generated by luaotfload?

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload, performance

`luatex` loads a lot of otf fonts at every `luaLaTeX` run with my custom class (Minion Pro, Myriad Pro, Minion Math, Latin Modern Mono, Latin Modern Math, XITS). This is an extract taken from my custom class:

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}


\RequirePackage[math-style = TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{MinionMath-Bold}
\setmathfont[Extension = .otf,
             Scale = 1,
             Script = Math,
             SizeFeatures = {%
                              {%
                                Size = -6, 
                                Font = MinionMath-Tiny,
                                Style = MathScriptScript},
                              {%
                                Size = 6-8.4, 
                                Font = MinionMath-Capt,
                                Style = MathScript},
                              {%
                                Size = 8.4-,
                                Font = MinionMath-Regular},
                            }
            ]{MinionMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[range={\mathfrak}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr}]{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={}]{MinionMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{unicode-minionmath}

\setmainfont{MinionPro}[
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-It,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldIt,
  ]

\setsansfont{MyriadPro}[
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Semibold,
  ItalicFont = *-It,
  BoldItalicFont = *-SemiboldIt,
  ]

\setmonofont{LatinModernMono}
```

On my system (linux, SSD, core i3), each run takes at least 10 seconds. If I understand correctly, much of the time is spent reading byte compiled lua tables storing all the information needed to take care of an `otf` font.

Having a look at those tables (stored in `~/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/`), it seems to me that most of the elements (unicode characters) there are nearly never used in my documents (written in French: I need ASCII + some accented letters, probably less than 200 characters).

**Questions**

1. Would `luaotfload` work if I build some lightweighted lua table files ?
2. Is there a tool to tweak those lua table files? If not, how can I do it manually and tell `luaotfload` to load it?
3. Will it speed up my compilation time?

**EDIT**

The answer to 2 might be building an appropriate subset of my fonts at font level with a tool like `fontforge`, thus creating a "new" lightweight font. As far as my googling can tell, this technique is used with web ttf fonts to minimize font size for downloads. So I add an item 4 to my questions: "Is subsetting a font a good way to downsize lua table files? Can I use fontforge to do the work with otf fonts? How? Is there any licence restriction?"

Comment: Probably [unrelated](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf) but still interesting.

Comment: Have you compared compilation times when you don't load any custom fonts? When you don't load `fontspec`? Note that LuaTeX automatically regenerates those files when needed, so if you replaced them, your versions would be liable to disappear.

Comment: @cfr Stripping down my class file to fonts only: 4.8s (it takes more or less 5s to load all `tikz`/`pgfplots`/`tcolorbox`/ most of Heiko & David packages / `expl3`  files, so I reach 10s). `fontspec` only: 1.5s. No `fontspec`: 0.3s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> luatex loads a lot of otf fonts at every luaLaTeX run with my
>   custom class […] On my system (linux, SSD, core i3), each run
>   takes at least 10 seconds.

Are you referring to one entire pass of Luatex? I can’t say
anything regarding Latex, but in Context that’s reached easily
with more complex documents.

> If I understand correctly, much of the time is spent reading
>   byte compiled lua tables storing all the information needed to
>   take care of an otf font.

Lua is a very efficient language. Parsing Lua programs is very
efficient. Loading byte-compiled programs even more. It’s
unlikely that this is the bottleneck you’re facing.

You can verify that easily: Determine the cache path (last line
of `luaotfload-tool -h`), list the subdirectory `otl/` and
select a bytecode file. The extension is `.luc`. I choose one
that is among the largest I know: kozminpr6n-regular.luc with
2,388,708 Bytes. These files are valid Lua programs so we can
load them directly with Luatex. For maximum IO penalty we also
clear the OS caches first:

```
$ sudo bash -c "echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
$ time texlua /home/phg/.local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/kozminpr6n-regular.luc 

real    0m0.240s
user    0m0.100s
sys     0m0.017s
```

---

**EDIT**

Some further measurements: I decided to check whether passing the
font loaded from cache to Luatex had a significant performance
impact. Turns out it’s negligible.

[Here’s a test setup](https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/9cc23b3fb414c797ee8a65276601bda1)
that loads a list of fonts and measures the runtime. For more
exact measurements it relies on the
[*luaposix*](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) library.
The timings are split into the cache retrieval per se
(`fonts.definers.read()`) and feeding the result into
`font.define()`.

[image: document with timings]

To summarize the results: Forcing the 38 fonts through the loader
adds 1.9 seconds to the runtime on my aged system; if the OS
caches are hot this figure shrinks to around 1.5 s. Complex fonts
from Adobe take around 50 ms to load. The huge
`kozminpr6n-regular.otf` is an outlier at ca. 300 ms for
retrieval plus 50 ms for passing through `font.define()`.

**END EDIT**

---

240s to load the Luatex binary, spawn the Lua interpreter, and
load one gigantic font table. On a low-end desktop from 2012. Not
bad, especially considering that fonts are usually loaded on
demand, not merely by virtue of being defined at some point.

> Would luaotfload work if I build some lightweighted lua table
>   files?

Those are cache files. They will be overwritten without asking
next time anything changes. You will have to hack on the
fontloader in order to make your changes stick.

> Is there a tool to tweak those lua table files?

As shown above, you can load them with Lua and manipulate them
like any ordinary table. The corresponding text representation
(in the `.lua` files) is plain text so you can use your editor.
But they need to be byte-compiled (`texluac(1)`) for use with
the loader.

> ```
>                                             If not, how can
> ```
>
> I do it manually and tell luaotfload to load it?

The fontloader will look up a font file in the cache first, but
it will also rewrite the cache if it doesn’t match the font file.
Thus you’ll have to hack the loader to avoid this.

> Will it speed up my compilation time?

Very unlikely. Loading byte code is very efficient and once the
tables are in memory, only those parts will be used that are
needed for processing the input.

> The answer to 2 might be building an appropriate subset of my
>   fonts at font level with a tool like fontforge

Throw out the tables you don’t like. That will reduce the table
size. Make sure you don’t violate the vendors’ license terms.
Some of them preclude any modification to the files.

> Having a look at those tables […] it seems to me that most of
>   the elements (unicode characters) there are nearly never used
>   in my documents (written in French: I need ASCII + some
>   accented letters, probably less than 200 characters).

If you only typeset Latin based copy, a more promising approach
would be to stick with `base` mode instead of `node` which
Luaotfload defaults to. That can speed up paragraph processing
drastically.

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time to answer this technical question. Could you elaborate a bit on the difference between `base` mode and `node` mode?

Comment: @cjorssen I’ve added some stats. Regarding ``node`` vs. ``base``: the latter applies the conventional TeX ligaturing plus kerning passes (see ``node.ligaturing``, ``node.kerning`` in the Luatex manual) whereas ``node`` mode performs Opentype text shaping (and more).